# Empty Space at the bottom of the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yui

A big blank/empty space generated after the footer container. My layout seems to be as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head></head>
    <body id="cms-body" class="yui-skin-sam">
        <div id="mainContainer" class="clearFix">
            <div id="headerDiv"></div>
            <div id="bodyDiv"></div>
            <div id="footerDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

We are using **Yahoo YUI Js/Styles** on our application. Issue raised when i navigate from more content page to less content page.

For instance: Big form page to less content page.

Please guide me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add any screen shot about your problem.

Comment: can you place this <div id="footerDiv"></div> into outside of div.clearFix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem due to visibility:hidden property of YUI. Instead of it, use display:none property, so, it reduces the blank white space at the footer.

Answer (score 0):

this should be your last div

```
<div id="footerDiv">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the height of the parent div?

Comment: Your main container height should depend on the height of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below style property,

```
#footerDiv{
 bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 position: relative;
}
```